# Need help translating a Korean word

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

There's this word that keeps coming up in a K-Drama - pantashe or pantachi something like that.  What does it mean?  The subtitles keep translating it differently.  When entering subtitles into Google Translate, it never comes out with the same English phrase.

Comment: Please link to an audio clip or post the actual word in question

Comment: What was the subtitle and it's translation?

Comment: 반드시? E.g. from the film 코리아 (09:22 in [this video](https://youtu.be/FrQIX3qa6rI?t=562)).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a Korean word pronouncing "Fantasy판타지".

In everyday conversation "판타지" could mean absurd, stupid attitude or idea.

-그건 판타지 같은 생각이고.
(Your idea is like a fantasy. => Your idea is unreasonable and stupid.)

Or sometimes, it is used to describe something came out from "fantasy novels"

-이 그림은 약간 판타지 같네요.
(This paintings feels kinda like fantasy. => This painting feels like it came out from the scene of Lord of the Rings)

Other times, literally it's a fantasy.
-저는 가수가 된다는 그런 판타지가 있었어요.
(I always had those fantasy of becoming a singer.)